# Turning strings into emojis using lua

Tags: lua, cryptography

So I am working on a encoding algorithm that changes letters in to emojis, but my algorithm returns nil on some characters, why is this?

```
local function enc(MSG)
    local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X","Y", "Z", " ", ".", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_", "*", "'", "^", "~", "!"}
    local resourcesT = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "⛹", "", "㊗️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☁️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛄️","", "↪️", "", "", "❗️", "", "", "", "", "️", "", "", "", "⚫️", "", "⭕️", "", "☣", "", "⏯", "", "", "", "", "⌛️", "⌨", "", "", "⏫", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#️⃣", "", "", "✖️", ""}
    local finalstring = ""
    local count = 0
    MSG:gsub(".", function(c)
    for i,v in pairs(resources) do
              count = count + 1
               if v == c then
                 finalstring = finalstring .. tostring(resourcesT[count])
                 count = 0
             end
         end
    end)
    return finalstring
end
local Enc = enc("Hello World")
local Thread = io.open("l.lua", "w")
Thread:write(Enc)
```

Comment: If the answer resolved, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep a track on the `count` variable, just use the available `i` variable and it will work fine:

```lua
local function enc(MSG)
    local resources = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X","Y", "Z", " ", ".", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "_", "*", "'", "^", "~", "!"}
    local resourcesT = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "⛹", "", "㊗️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☁️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛄️","", "↪️", "", "", "❗️", "", "", "", "", "️", "", "", "", "⚫️", "", "⭕️", "", "☣", "", "⏯", "", "", "", "", "⌛️", "⌨", "", "", "⏫", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "#️⃣", "", "", "✖️", ""}
    local finalstring = ""
    MSG:gsub(".", function(c)
        for i, v in ipairs(resources) do
                if v == c then
                    finalstring = finalstring .. tostring(resourcesT[i])
                end
            end
    end)
    return finalstring
end
local Enc = enc("Hello World") --
```

You can see this code working [here](https://lua.ceifa.tv/?paste=oxalegavig).